# Enable automatic checksum for AWS S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, pre-signed-url

AWS released additional checksum integrity validation using SHA, CRC.
In their put method we can specify the Checksum algorithm and an optional pre-computed checksum to validate against that.

I want to know if we can achieve the same functionality when using pre-signed url.
I don't want to pre-compute the SHA256 checksum but I want AWS to compute and store it automatically like it does without forcing me to send the pre-computed checksum.

I wrote the following code to generate the pre-signed URLs

```
url = self.s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                             Params={
                                                 'Bucket': self.bucket_name,
                                                 'Key': key,
                                                 'ChecksumAlgorithm': 'sha256',
                                                 'ChecksumSHA256': 'None'
                                             },
                                             ExpiresIn=expiration)
```

With the above code the URL is generated but on PUT it is asking me to provide the pre computed sha256 header.
Any work around to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: AWS does not compute the checksum for you when using the SDK, rather the SDK calculates it.  Since the SDK is not involved in an upload with the presigned URL, you'll need to compute the checksum.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for AWS to "to compute and store it automatically" would be after the upload operation. Which does not make any sense, as you want to ensure that your original file was correctly uploaded to AWS in the first place. This means that you have to calculate the checksum, before upload operation. AWS does not know what you upload, before you upload it to AWS.

Comment: Actually, most sdks do this during (not before) the upload operation and appends the checksum it generates as a trailer. If you generate a presigned URL and manually include your own trailing checksum as an http trailer it might work. If it doesn't, then a bug should be cut to AWS.

Comment: But, is there a way to tell to any S3 bucket that simply calculate the checksum X for each any createds object?